# Can I restrict advanced search to the related questions for a given question?

Tags: feature-request, search, filtering, related-questions

Given an existing question, is there a way to do advanced search or filtering on the related questions that appear in the sidebar?

When I find a question that I have a good answer to, I'd love to be able to find the related questions with few answers, or few upvotes or no accepts.

Or, given a frequently asked question, I'd like to be able to filter the related questions for high votes, plus certain tags and keywords, so that I can link to the best cannonical answer, as opposed to the first one I find.

Comment: That's not currently possible AFAIK.  Would be a nice request to be able to tho.

Comment: Should probably be tagged feature request then, not support